# How to check which IAM performed an object modification of an s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is there a way to see which IAM did a modification on a aws s3 bucket object (with versioning enabled)?

I know that there is the `aws s3api list-object-versions`, but it only shows the owner's DisplayName and ID (owner of aws organisation), not the underlying IAM that performed the modification.

```
"Owner": {
    "DisplayName": "my-username",
    "ID": "7009a8971cd660687538875e7c86c5b672fe116bd438f46db45460ddcd036c32"
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to configure CloudTrail. This service monitors calls to the AWS platform and can also monitor S3 API calls, logging the user information you require.

More details here:

[Logging Amazon S3 API Calls by Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html)